# How to add module to Android's build?

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, makefile

I am familiar with how to [build](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/build_system.html) a full Android repository.  I want to add my own tests files under  `system/extras/tests` and to build them and all the projects in `system/extras/tests`.

***What is the right sequence for doing this?***